# Calling service bus running on cloud from my local application

Tags: servicebus

How can i call service bus running on cloud from my local application.If there is some demo then please share the link

Comment: i want to start that.I want the solution how i can call service bus running on cloud from my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/) site to download the SDK for the language you are using. Then head over to the service bus [samples site](http://servicebus.codeplex.com/) to get an idea on some demos.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all the azure service bus sample code were developed and tested on local machines. Unless your organization has some special firewall settings, it should just work. Let us know what u get.